# Typescript don't allow to use "as" property which is returned from handler function with Input Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I want to use Input from Chakra UI and this component should have different "as" property depending on type props passed to the component.
Result is delivered by handler function where types are checked.

Please find the code:

```
const typeHandler = (arg: string) => {
    if (arg === 'number') return NumericFormat;
    if (arg === 'phone') return <PhoneInput />;
    return InputMask;
  };

<Input
          as={typeHandler(type)}
          {...rest}
          type={getType()}
          id={id}
          name={id}
          value={values}
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          accept={accept}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          px="16px"
          {...(type === 'number' && numericFormatProps)}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
```

Comment I get from typescript is that:

[image]

Can You please suggest what should be corrected in the code ?

thanks

Comment: The as prop expects a certain type, and the value returned by your `typeHandler` function doesn't match that expected type.

Instead of returning JSX elements from typeHandler, you can return the component types themselves. This will make it easier for TypeScript to understand what you're trying to do.